# Preferences tech list

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If the list is pretty long the list starts with the latest, eg:
[image]

Using arrow keys is possibile to go back to the first.

Comment: It looks like a regression of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250491/in-ie-11-the-first-tag-tries-to-escape-the-tags-box), I noticed it on main as well if you do an inline edit of tags